# How does memory allocate for struct and union in C program?

Tags: c

In structure, memory space will be created for all members inside structure.
In union memory space will be created only for a member which needs largest memory space.
Consider the following code:

```
struct s_tag
{
   int a;
   long int b;
} x;

struct s_tag
{
   int a;
   long int b;
} x;

union u_tag
{
   int a;
   long int b;
} y;

union u_tag
{
   int a;
   long int b;
} y;
```

Here there are two members inside struct and union: int and long int. Memory space for int is: 4 byte and Memory space for long int is: 8

So for struct 4+8=12 bytes will be created while 8 bytes will be created for union. I run the following code to see a proof:
C

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct s_tag
{
  int a;
  long int b;
} x;
union u_tag
{
     int a;
     long int b;
} y;
int main()
{
    printf("Memory allocation for structure = %d", sizeof(x));
    printf("\nMemory allocation for union = %d", sizeof(y));
    return 0;
}
```

But I can see the following output:

```
Memory allocation for structure = 16
Memory allocation for union = 8
```

Why memory allocation for struct is 16 instead of 12? Is there any wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the requirement for aligning memory access on X byte boundaries.  Also, it's up to the compiler - it can do what it likes.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler adds invisible padding bytes between the two struct members which make sure that the address of the `long` member is a multiple of `sizeof(long)`, so that the variable is correctly aligned in memory. Depending on the CPU architecture, if a variable is not correctly aligned, accesses to it might crash the program, result in incorrect values, just be slow or work as expected.

Comment: Not `sizeof(long)` but `_Alignof(long)`

Comment: Right, but they are often equal.